# Is there a workaround for an [Error 18]: invalid cross-device link while calling 'pip' with Popen?

Tags: python, pip, popen

I am trying to create a GUI for working with the pip command with a text editor.  Currently I am receiving an `[Error 18]: Invalid cross-device link` which traces back to `os.rename` which my program does not explicitly call.

I believe that this error occurs because pip is trying to call on a temporary file located on the /tmp/ file system and the actual folders are on the /usr/ file system (same computer different mount points).  I have tried to resolve this by creating a new temporary directory in my current working directory via `tempfile.TemporaryDirectory(dir='./')` and feeding that into my Popen(..., cwd=NewTempDir).  I have also tried setting the `os.environ['TMPDIR'] = NewTempDir` and both of these still lead to the `Error 18`.

```py
    self.tmp = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory(dir='./')
    os.environ['TMPDIR'] = self.tmp

    ....

    self.sp = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', \
        pip_dict['process'], pip_dict['package']], \
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, \ 
        cwd=self.tmp.name)

    ....
    while True:
        stdout = self.sp.stdout.read(1)
            self.stdout += stdout
            print(self.stdout)
            if b'Proceed (y/n)?' in self.stdout:
                try:
                    print('attempting response')
                    self.sp.stdin.write(b'y\n')
                    self.sp.stdin.flush()
                    break
                except:
                    print('stdin write failed')
```

I expect the output to be the uninstalling of the named package.

My current output is:

```
    Exception:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/usr/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 563, in move
            os.rename(src, real_dst)
    OSError: [Errno 18] Invalid cross-device link: 
        '/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anytree' -> '/tmp/pip- 
        uninstall-ye0w908_'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-\ 
            packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 179, in 
            main
        status = self.run(options, args)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site- 
      packages/pip/_internal/commands/uninstall.py", line 75, in run
      auto_confirm=options.yes, verbose=self.verbosity > 0,
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site- 
      packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 817, in uninstall
      uninstalled_pathset.remove(auto_confirm, verbose)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site- 
      packages/pip/_internal/req/req_uninstall.py", line 360, in remove
      moved.stash(path)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site- 
      packages/pip/_internal/req/req_uninstall.py", line 257, in stash
      renames(path, new_path)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", 
      line 303, in renames
      shutil.move(old, new)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 575, in move
      rmtree(src)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 491, in rmtree
      _rmtree_safe_fd(fd, path, onerror)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 449, in _rmtree_safe_fd
      onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 447, in _rmtree_safe_fd
      os.unlink(entry.name, dir_fd=topfd)
    PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'search.py'
```

I do receive `print("attempting response")` before the code breaks.

Here is the link to the full program file... https://github.com/rscales02/porcupine/blob/pipgui/porcupine/plugins/pip_plugin.py

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see `[Error 18]: Invalid cross-device link` in a call to `rename()`, I see `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'search.py'` in a call to `unlink()`.